# .htaccess multiple domain redirect to once https without www

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, https

i have few domains:

www.xxx.com
xxx.com

www.xxx.co
xxx.co

www.xx.io
xxx.io

how to redirect all domains to https://xxx.io?

I have a redirect to https without www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rule in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example.io [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.io%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The condition checks to see if the URL is either `www.example.io` or `exmaple.io` and if it isn't, then it will rewrite to it.

I've used `R=301` which is a permanent redirection. For testing purposes, I advise you change this to `R` or `R=302`, which is temporary.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

Comment: Ok, You are my hero, Thanks! ;)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following lines to your .htaccess file located at the root of your xxx.io domain:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx.co$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://xxx.io/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```